# iFrame - iOS scrolling with Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

I have a webpage where I am adding an iframe (only for mobile).

What I hope to do is add this iframe, which is set to take up 100% width and height, and then stop the user from being able to scroll out of the iframe (e.g. they open the iframe, they are on the iframe until they hit "Exit inventory". Scrolling down doesn't return to the normal page).

An example of this which I found and is pretty great is here: http://www.liveperson.com/

If you open on mobile and hit the button which appears on the right, it opens a screen where it says "Cancel" and "Next". If you try to scroll here, it keeps pulling you back up and doesn't seem to even move the iframe.

Any advice on this please?

Note that I've tried adding "overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" to the iframe but that just hides the entire frame...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it's position to 'fixed' and then lock it to the top of the screen?

```
iframe {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

This way you iframe will always cover the whole screen until you close it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The reason for using iframe is to bypass the "position: fixed" issue with iOS and the keyboard so this solution still has the same issue.

Comment: Also, this still lets me scroll the page. I would prefer if the user was totally unable to scan as in the link above. Thanks!